# How to overlay an image over video in percent

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to overlay an image on top of a video and have reached these two links:

[How to overlay/place an image on a video in ffmpeg [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480153/how-to-overlay-place-an-image-on-a-video-in-ffmpeg)

[Add an image overlay in front of video using ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg)

And this is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i flower.mp4 -i rose.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=W-w/2:H-h/2" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy flowers.mp4 -y
```

But I have not reached the thing I want yet.

I want the image be placed in top right with 10 percent space from right and 3 percent from top, or 10px from right and 5px from top right.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZRbMFHx.png]

How to reach this to work with my desired percent?

There are some other videos with different scales, so I cannot use fix x and y for all of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

for 10% space from right, and 3% from top,

```
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=x='0.90*W-w':y='0.03*H'"
```

for 10 px from right, and 5 px from top,

```
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=x='W-10-w':y='5'"
```